# How do you reassign an Xbox controller's ID under Windows without rebooting?

Tags: controllers, windows-7

I had a controller connected as #1. The plug was loose, and it disconnected. When I reconnected, it was #2. Subsequent connections and disconnections always result in #2. Can this be changed without rebooting?

Comment: The easy answer is to reboot and resync the xbox controller.

Comment: From the OP: "Can this be changed without rebooting?" I am fully aware that rebooting will reset it. Note the question mentions plugs; it's not synced because it is a wired controller.

Comment: You can disable and re-enable the port?

Comment: I tried disabling and re-enabling the HID listing in the Device manager. I don't see how to tell which Universal Serial Bus controller the thing is attached to so I could reset the port directly.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit Enterprise.